# Download attribute html link just opens to a new page?

Tags: html

I am trying to allow users to download a file. I took this example here:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download

When I click their w3 photo I get a jpg download in Chrome.

However, when I copy their html onto my local machine into a plain static html file, I open the html file in Chrome, then I attempt to download that file, and then Chrome just opens up the photo in a different window without downloading anything. Anyone know what's the problem?

My code (which is almost the exact same):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The a download attribute</h1>

<p>Click on the image to download it:<p>
<a href="images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  <img src="images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>

<p><b>Note:</b> The download attribute is not supported in IE or Edge (prior version 18), or in Safari (prior version 10.1).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I downloaded the w3 image locally onto my computer so it should'n't be a cross site origin issue

Comment: It also helps to set `Content-Disposition:` in the file's HTTP response too.

Comment: @Dai I read that it's not necessary since html5 has the download attribute. In any case I don't have a server to set that right now. Why would it be needed for me?

Answer (score 1):

You would be better served studying almost anywhere but w3schools.

But more to your problem, are you running a webserver locally, or depending on file:/// links?

- incognito mode will not impact your testing in any way.

A quick glance at google results for ‘download from file:/// link fails’ will show that there are an host of issues surrounding local file downloads and the file:/// links, especially on chrome.

This is not surprising - chrome is a *browser* not a web server.

Where the semantics of such ‘downloads’ are inconsistently defined for browsers, the semantics of true downloads are well defined, and their behavior consistent in a true service context.

To further both your understanding of these tools and the goals of your project, I strongly encourage you to download and install a webserver for your platform and learn the basics of it’s configuration and deployment.

You will not regret having done so.

Comment: I'm using depending on file:/// links  This is just an html file. It doesn't have anything else

Comment: It actually does make a difference potentially. Most likely the reason it’s opening locally instead of downloading is that the browser has it cached and knows that the file is stored locally.

Comment: Tried it in incognito and still doesn't work. In any case the image is supposed to be downloaded regardless of whether its cached or not

Comment: This "Answer" is a comment. Do not put comments here in the Answer section. Please delete this.

Comment: Rob, you should address yourself to someone particular if you are going to suggest a particular course of action.